# Issue with forman provisioning without puppet agent

Tags: foreman

My goal is to configure foreman without installing puppet agent so I set for a test in kickstart provisioning template variable puppet_enabled as false.

```
...
proxy_string = proxy_uri ? " --proxy=#{proxy_uri}" : ''
#puppet_enabled = pm_set || @host.param_true?('force-puppet')
puppet_enabled = false
salt_enabled = @host.params['salt_master'] ? true : false
...
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work as I expected, because puppet CA has to sign certificate to finish build process. I found info in manual 4.4.6.5 Example: Anaconda PXE-based provisioning step 15. Without puppet foreman goes into infinite loop with installation,and after reboot try to install OS again.

My question is is it possible to provision OS completely without foreman agent ?

Answer (score 0):

I found solution for my question so below short summary:

Puppet agent doesn't have to be installed on vm to finish build. Just wget command at the end of script have to inform Foreman that build is done. So make sure that you have wget installed and it has access to Foreman. Below part of provisioning template responsible for that.

```
echo "Informing Foreman that we are built"
wget -q -O /dev/null --no-check-certificate <%= foreman_url('built') %>
) 2>&1 | tee /root/install.post.log
exit 0
```